# Woocommerce conditional is_product() from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I want to check if is single product page, but this has no effect on single product page:

```php
if (! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
    var_dump('is product'); // this has no effect in single product page
}
```

Is there a limitation to use `is_product()` in functions.php? How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

In order to avoid `var_dump` issues, this is the final code I'm trying. It try to add product type (simple/variable) to body class:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', function () {
    if (! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
            global $post;
            $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
            $tipo = $product->get_type();
            return array_merge( $classes, array( $tipo ) );
        });
    }
}, 100 );
```

Comment: Please show the full code. Using it in the functions.php without a hook don't works since when the function.php is included the function is not available.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and sorry, i think this is the complete code for now). Anyway, it point me in the right direction. Could you suggest what action should I hook from?

Comment: Tried: `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', function () {//etc}, 100)`doesn't work.

Comment: Depends or where you want to check if you are on the product page. And dumping something out inside a hook normally don't works (depends on the hook at the end).

Comment: in that case I must rephrase the question without var_dump.

Comment: Please always show the full code. It matters a lot for a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use this function directly without a hook since your `functions.php` file is included before every other file - mostly. To make this thing work you need to work with hooks every time like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_action' );
function template_redirect_action() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        add_filter( 'body_class', function ( $classes ) {
            global $post;
            $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
            $tipo    = $product->get_type();

            return array_merge( $classes, array( $tipo ) );
        } );
    }
}
```

Visit a product page and check your body classes.

By using the `template_redirect` hook you can be sure it's executed on every page. Otherwise your check would not make any sense when using a product hook which only gets executed on product pages.

Tested an works.